# TypeError: argument 1 must be string or read-only character buffer, not None

Tags: python, cgi

I am gertting values from HTML file and getting
Getting TracebackError: I am not getting to what should i change ?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 33, in <module>
    get_data()
  File "test.py", line 25, in get_data
    f.write(form.getvalue('firstname'))
TypeError: argument 1 must be string or read-only character buffer, not None
```

My python Code:

```
# !/usr/bin/python
import cgi

def get_data():
    '''
    This function writes the HTML data into the file 

    '''

    print "Content- type : text/html\n"

    form = cgi.FieldStorage()

    #Fname = form.getvalue('firstname')
    #Lname = form.getvalue('lastname')
   #Age = form.getvalue('age')
   #Gender = form.getvalue('gender')

    f = open("abc.txt","w")

    f.write(form.getvalue('firstname'))
    f.write(form.getvalue('lastname'))
    f.write(form.getvalue('age'))
    f.write(form.getvalue('gender'))
    f.close()

#print "Hello ", Fname, Lname, Age, Gender

get_data()
```

I am an newbie. and unable to get the error. please help me with that

HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>INFORMATION</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form action = "/cgi-bin/test.py" method = "post">
FirstName:
<input type = "text" name = "firstname" /><br>
LastName:
<input type = "text" name = "lastname" /><br>
Age:
<input type = "text" name = "age" /><br>
Gender:
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" /> Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" /> Female

<input type = "submit" name = "submit "value = "SUBMIT">
<input type = "reset" name = "reset" value = "RESET">
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not your problem, but it's worth noting that it's best to [use the `with` statement](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRaKmobSXF4) to work with files.

Comment: Seems like the `firstname` field is empty or missing. Can you show the HTML that's producing the form to be submitted?

Comment: @Lattyware He's using Python 2.6 (from previous question), and can't use `with`.

Comment: `form.getvalue('firstname')` is `None`. Probably, it is not getting value from `FieldStorage`.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac `with` and context managers were added in 2.5 if you use `from __future__ import with_statement`, and in 2.6 it's available by default.

Comment: please fix the indentation. It's essential in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form.getvalue('firstname')` is returning `None`, and not the string that you expect it to, thats why you're getting an error.

Comment: OKay. I am filling up the form clicking submit button and nothing happens

Comment: @johnjohn Then that is a separate problem. The thing is, the problem as you've presented it, shows that you get a `None`, now we do not know what kind of function `form.getValue()` returns.

Comment: But when using a print its showing okay on submit button. Whwn same writing to file, it shows error